# Change Tracking in Excel

Tags: c#, sql, .net, excel

To avoid polling `MS Excel` file, I am looking something similar to `SqlDependency` class which can alert the application about changes in the file.

Also, is there something similar like [SQL Change Tracking feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx), for MS Excel (2010 or above)?

My sole purpose is to display excel file contents in `GridView` and update `GridView` with the newly inserted rows in excel.

I went through [ListObject.Change Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.listobject.change.aspx), but it works for a selected range and returns the cells which are changed. But I am in need to newly inserted or deleted rows (no cell-editing or updating required).

Comment: your simplest fix would be to stop using `Excel as a DataBase` and store all your data in a Database Excel is not a `Database`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subscribe to the [`Workbook.SheetChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196611(v=office.14).aspx) event for changes to any sheet in the workbook, or the [`Worksheet.Change`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775(v=office.14).aspx) event for changes to a particular sheet.

Excel has no concept of "adding" or "deleting" rows like SQL, so there's no way to pinpoint to just those types of events - you'll have to determine *what* changed in your event handler and decide if you want to do anything about it or not.

Or stop using Excel as a database :)